# Real analysis using some key constraints

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $\alpha>1$ and $M \geq 0$. Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}$ satisfies $$|f(x)-f(y)| \leq M|x-y|^\alpha$$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb R$. Prove that $f$ is a constant function.

I tried taking different values of $M$ and $\alpha$ like $M=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\alpha=2$. But with that I get the condition $$|f(x)-f(y)| \leq \frac{1}{2}|x-y|^2.$$ But how do I prove that $f$ is a constant function?

Comment: try to show that $f$ is differentiable with zero derivative.

Comment: $\alpha$ and $M$ are arbitrary; taking specific values is not a useful approach.

Answer (score 2):

Fix $x\in \mathbb R$.

If $\alpha >1$ then we may write it as $\alpha =1+\epsilon $ for some $\epsilon >0$. Then

$$|f(x)-f(y)| \leq M|x-y|^\alpha\Rightarrow \left | \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} \right |<M\vert x-y\vert ^{\epsilon }.$$

Letting $y\to x$ we see that $f'(x)=0$ and the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

We need to show that $f(.)$ is continuous over R and also, its derivative is equal to zero everywhere. The first part can be easily proved using the definition of continuity and the inequality which $f(.)$ satisfies. For the second part, we need to show that
$$\forall x\in R;\ \lim_{\epsilon\to0} \frac{f(x+\epsilon)-f(x)}{\epsilon}=0$$
To do this, first use the given inequality to get
$$|\frac{f(x+\epsilon)-f(x)}{\epsilon}|\leq M\epsilon^{\alpha-1}$$
Now, using *Sandwich* argument and considering, $\lim_{\epsilon\to0}M\epsilon^{\alpha-1}=0$ (remember $\alpha\geq1$) it can be concluded that
$$\forall x\in R;\ \frac{df(x)}{dx}=0$$
Therefore, $f(.)$ is a constant function

Comment: Continuity follows from differentiability. No need for an extra proof :D